# Why does sed delete the wrong range of lines

Tags: sed, range, line

Im trying to write a script that deletes a certain range of lines using the sed command. I first printed out the lines.

```
    sed -n '482,486p' original.json
                {
                    "vlans": "ALL",
                    "hostname": "hostname",
                    "interface": "interface"
                },
```

After confirming that those are the lines I executed the following code

```
sed '482,486d' original.json > new.json
```

When I ran the diff command I got the following results

```
diff original.json new.json
484,488d483
<                     "hostname": "hostname",
<                     "interface": "interface"
<                 },
<                 {
<                     "vlans": "ALL",
```

My question is why was the range of lines from 484-448 deleted when I specified lines 482-486 to be deleted and how do I fix it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use a JSON-aware tool like `jq` instead of `sed` to manipulate JSON files.

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce on a test file (With just one number per line). Same lines get printed as get deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I dont have the rights to install jq on my system.

Comment: Go tell whoever does that you don't process .json with shell utilities. (you will spend twice the time fixing corrupted .json files in the long run) There is nothing wrong with your `sed` syntax, there is something wrong with your input file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information to reproduce the error, but I'll go out on a limb.

My guess is that lines 487 and 488 of the original file are

```
{
    "vlans": "ALL",
```

So if we put the `original` and the `new` side by side, it looks like this:

```
481 ...     481 ...
482 {       487 {
483 vlans   488 vlans
484 host    489 ...
485 int
486 }
487 {
488 vlans
489 ...
```

So lines 482-486 were excised from `original`, but diff sees everything matching up through line 483, then five lines 484-488 in `original` not appearing in `new`, and then all the rest matching.

Comment: i tried to update as best I could. If you guys could please check it out. Im trying my best to understand but Im still new to linux.

Comment: @trentshin: What's left to understand? Your `sed` command worked exactly as you intended. Your `diff` command gave you something you didn't expect, because of an ambiguity. Suppose you ask me to compare "ABBC" and "ABC", and because I am simple-minded and read from left to right, I say *"the first string has an extra 'B' at location 3".* Then you scratch your head and say "I was trying to erase the character at position *two.* What happened?" I could say "well, yeah, that would explain it too", but `diff` isn't that sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I finally got it and appreciate everyones help. Sorry for causing such a fuss